# What ring is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(2)}$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I'm trying to find a ring isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(2)}$ using the first isomorphism theorem.

I thought maybe $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ was a solution, but I was unable to find a ringmophism to use the isomorphism theorem.

Thanks!